# OS Simulator 14 runnning iOS 16 not displaying keyboard

Tags: ios, macos, keyboard, ios-simulator

just upgraded my entire Mac environment for my cordova app development to the latest macOS now running Xcode 14.2.  MacOS Simulator is also 14.2.  When I deploy my app to simulator devices, on my first test of my app a screen that has a text input properly popped up the on-screen keyboard once.  It was a bit wonky where I couldn't type anything and then it slid to the bottom of the screen and stayed there - slightly revealing the top bar of the keyboard overlay (I can see the `Done` at the right of the status bar and nothing else).

I completely closed simulator and restarted and now on my app the keyboard is permanently stuck at the bottom.  On other native/default apps that boot with the device, when I click on a text input fields no keyboard comes up at all.

On previous Simulators (v13) my app always displayed the virtual keyboard just fine...I never checked default apps so I can't say if the keyboard popped up there or not.  Is this a changed behavior or is this a bug - anyway to fix it?

Comment: A few questions: 1) Is this an iPad or an iPhone simulator? 2) Can you please share a screenshot? 3) Have you tried `⌘K`?

Comment: @VadimBelyaev - iPhone simulator.  I had just did the `I/O -> toggle software keyboard` (aka the `Cntrl-K`) right before you responded and the keyboard popped right back onto the screen and seems to work cleanly now on all screens.  I then tested another simulator device model and it works cleanly on all screens too.  Gonna chalk this one up as another `glitchy macky`.

Answer (score 0):

Command-K (Cntrl-K) does a simulator `toggle software keyboard` and that popped the keyboard back on to the screen again.  Seems to be working fine now on that device and other simulator devices too.  Just another Mac glitch.